# how to get balance by USSD commands?

Tags: modem, ussd

I have tired to search how to send USSD command on Google.
I want to check may balance from operator.

All of the samples I have seen use commands like this:

```
 "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\"\r\n";
```

It seems to be correct. I am using something like this that I think works. I have a D-Link GSM modem, and when I send this command using it, it makes some noise on my speaker, which I believe tells me something happened.

my modem have it's own windows application when i disconnected modem by my own application,i check it by modem's application and in USSD tab i can found the result of my commands that i sent by myself application.

then that command works fine but i 'm confuse what is happens when i sent my command it return me "OK" and do not return operator answer and how my modem's application can read that answer????????

i test these commands but can not get result and my modem just return somethings like this:
"AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\"\r\n\OK\r\n"  only.

```
1) "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\",15\r\n"

2) "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\",1\r\n"

3) "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\",15\r"

4) "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\",1\r"

5) "AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*1#\""
```

i think reading command's result maybe has difference command or i should set some config on my modem .

it is very interesting for me that my modem do not return error to me and always return OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I found that my modem use more than one port and i should connect at the first port to send my command and listen to another port to get the USSD command's result

Comment: How are the ports named?

Comment: if you look at Control Panel\System and Security\System and click on devices manager you will find the installed ports names

Comment: I know. I'm interested how the ones you mentioned are named in your case.

Comment: @motevalizadeh how do i listen to another port to get the USSD command's result?

Comment: @Spidy there are two ports, take a look at your devise manager(in windows), modems use one port (COM1 as an example) to send commands and another port (COM2 as an example) to get the results of commands.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the Message format to AT+CMGF=0, before sending your USSD Command. This is PDU Mode (http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html). I was stumped using AT+CMGF=1, which is Text mode, before I decided to try AT+CMGF=0.

Worked like Magic.

So:

1. Set Message Format to PDU (AT+CMGF=0)
2. Execute Your USSD Command (AT+CUSD=1,*544*2*3#,15) - example message
3. Read response from the Port.

I am assuming that you know already how to form your AT Commands and Read the response from the Port.

Answer (score 1):

Try This using **Hyperterm** Serial Monitor Application ( https://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal-trial/ )

First Convert Modem to PDU Mode :

```
AT+CMGF=0
```

Second USSD Code Send :

```
AT+CUSD=1,"#132#",15
```

( Use your Country Carrier Codes )

Finally Read Output from Terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

i just use this "AT+CUSD=1,'*120#',15" in my country the USSD code is *120# but remember if you are using it withing a code you must add crlf character to the end hope this help